# Updating in mongodb document isnt working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update my MongoDB document but its not updating due to some issue

At first my document "stories" look like this

```
_id:               ObjectId("5e8b88e38d18020c742d1e8e")
storyTitle:        "story 1 ratnabh"
storyDescription:  "story 1"
categoryID:        "5e882ed701e2ba37407328f1"
userID:            "5e896bc2feeed13a5336c066"
dateAdded:         2020-04-06T19:54:11.867+00:00
```

Now in post request, I am sending userID, `storyId`, and `userEmail` and getting it in a variable called "data" as an object

```
{
  storyID: '5e8b88e38d18020c742d1e8e',
  userEmail: 'indroneelray@gmail.com',
  userID: '5e86f4c4e508670e9abe46ea'
}
```

After this, I am running my MongoDB query which is setting reported to increase by 1 every time but isn't creating a new field

> reportedBy
>   which should be an array containing all email ids that I get

in document

```
  let reportStory = await req.db
      .collection("stories")
      .updateOne({ _id: data.storyID }, {$inc:{reported:1}},{$push:{reportedBy:data.userEmail}} );
```

so this query isn't working

and also after `console.log(reportStory)` it isn't showing me the document it is giving me a huge object with too many details

Comment: Try this : `const ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectId;
let reportStory = await req.db
  .collection("stories")
  .updateOne(
    { _id: new ObjectId(data.storyID) },
    { $inc: { reported: 1 }, $push: { reportedBy: data.userEmail } }
  );` You need to convert string to `ObjectId()` on `_id` field & also `.updateOne()`'s second parameter is update operation but you're having 3, where as 3rd one if for options.

Comment: @whoami done but only first query i,e reported workd the second one reportedBy doesnt works

Comment: Are you sure(Did you actually take the query from comment) ? It should work, To double check -I tested it & it worked, If it's not first test it on DB & check(it doesn't matter much though)..